# Dropzone not binding files to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am not able to post files using dropzone.js to controller. I have a parameter IEnumerable files. All data can be posted except dropzone files. 
My code:

//Html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm">
         <div class="fallback">
            <input name="files" type="file" multiple/>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

//Javascript:

```
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneForm", {
        url:'/TravelPlaces/Create',
        paramName: 'files',
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 25,
        maxFiles: 5
    });

    //Called by submit 
    function uploadClicked() {
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    }


    //Here is my Controller Code:
    // I have two other file uploader in the same form as well.

    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TravelPlaceID,Title,PlaceDescription,Logo,CountryID,State,ProvinceID,DistrictID,Address,Location,OtherMap,ServicesID")] TravelPlace travelPlace,HttpPostedFileBase Logo,HttpPostedFileBase OtherMap,IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
  {
      foreach (var p in files)
      {
        var z = p.FileName;
      }

   }
```

Comment: Thanks for edit @tersko
seems no one is here ..

Comment: You should be showing your controller post action code as well...

Comment: Thanks for response. I have edited my post.@Martin

Comment: Dropzone.js defaults to POST. Your `ActionResult` is a GET, either change it in dropzone to `GET` or put `[HttpPost]` attribute on method. Also, does the `ActionResult` get called when you upload and the files are null or does it never get called?

Comment: My action result is in post method also get called when form submited.Except "files" field value,other fields value are submitted well.Only "files" parameter shows null.